Large voltage drop under circuit load…
03 mazda protege
With key on engine off (KOEO) if I load the power window circuit, my voltage goes from 12.6 volts to 10 volts. This only occurs if I continue holding the window switch down after the window hits the bottom of its travel. When actually rolling down voltage only drops to 12.4v which is normal.
With key on engine running (KOER) if I turn on my headlights there is a noticeable rpm drop although it is slight. If I conduct the same window switch test with the headlights and engine on the headlights dim out and the alternator doesn’t seem to “pick up” lost voltage. Even accelerating from a stop the headlights will dim out and then brighten back up. All grounds are functioning properly with no resistance. Primary power cable is working properly with no resistance faults.
the only thing I can think of would be that the alternator had a large amount of water splashed on it and the main fuse (100A) blew. I replaced the failed alternator and the main fuse. Not sure if the fuse block was damaged or if any wiring was harmed although no other fuses were burnt.
battery tested fine when I conducted an internal resistance and load test with my professional testers.

Where exactly are you measuring voltage?

At the switch and at the battery, both show the same drop to 10v

It happens wether engine is running or not, so long as the ignition switch is set to “on” so the electrical system is “awake” the voltage drop will occur

No, I mean where exactly? On the soft lead battery posts or on the battery cable clamps? A resistance of only 0.1 ohms at each clamp -- too low to measure accurately with a typical multimeter -- will give you that voltage drop if the stalled window motor is drawing 25 amps. (V=IR) Suggest you measure VOLTS between the battery post and clamp during window motor stall, and if it's more than the low mV range you have poor conductivity between post and clamp.

I measure resistance between battery post and chassis ground during the drop… resistance was 0 when rolling down and 2ohms when at the stop. I measure between the terminal posts for voltage not the terminal leads that connect to the battery cable

There's no such thing as "no resistance" unless your car is in a tank of liquid helium. You're trying to measure resistance in the milliohm range with (I assume) a typical digital multimeter, and that's just not possible. Milliohms matter when you're dealing with heavy currents. As stated above, just a 100 milliohm resistance on each battery cable clamp will give you the voltage drop that you measured.
You're also trying to measure resistance under load, but that load is creating a voltage across your resistance that interferes with the meter's own applied voltage that's used to calculate resistance. That 2 ohm resistance reading will change (possibly to impossible negative resistance) if you reverse the meter's leads, which means that the 2 ohm measurement is invalid.
You can measure actual resistance in the milliohm range by running a known current (amps) through a connection and measuring the voltage in millivolts across the connection. But the current draw of your stalled window motor is unknown. If you follow the procedure in the comment above and assume 25 amps, you'll learn the battery terminal resistance +/- 50% or so.
In order to diagnose the possible alternator issue, you need something like a carbon pile battery tester to create a known and variable amp load for the alternator, a clamp-on DC ammeter and a digital voltmeter.
Before you even go there though, I suggest you measure battery voltage directly on the battery posts during window motor stall. If the battery post voltage is in the 10 volt range with this modest window motor current, you have a bad battery regardless of what the battery tester is saying.
For a proper battery test, fully charge the battery, then subject it to a load of 50% of the battery's CCA. (That's going to be 200-400 amps or so, requiring a carbon pile tester.) Maintain that current for 15 seconds, then measure battery voltage at the last moment of testing. If the battery voltage at that moment is less than about 10.5 volts, depending on temperature, the battery is past its useful life. Electronic battery testers that don't put a heavy amp load on the battery are worse than useless.
Once you know you have a good battery and you have a measured battery cable clamp and ground connection resistance in the low milliohm range, you can start troubleshooting the alternator by placing it under a known amp load at various engine RPM and watching how the voltage changes.

Ok that all makes sense. I know everything outside of electrical. I know the basics of electrical in automotive systems and it’s funny because I can diagnose CANbus, LIN, MOST, and flex ray without any issue but when it comes to loads and resistance I am pretty dumb. Maybe a lack of equipment or something. But yes when I test with the key on, engine off and test voltage across the 2 battery posts (+ and -) and I stall out the window motor or any of the window motors for that case voltage does drop to 10 volts until I release the window switch.

I guess what I was trying to say with resistance is that it’s very low. I set the multimeter to the 200 ohms setting and I get 0.02 ohms when testing either the ground strap from battery negative post to chassis ground location if that makes sense.

@lockheed OK then, 10 volts on the battery posts at such a low current (estimated 25-40 amps) is 100% diagnostic of of a bad battery, assuming that the battery is not nearly discharged. The battery tester that you're using must put a very low current drain on the battery, which is not valid. If you want to be 110% sure, make sure the battery is fully charged then take it for a load test as described above. Or if you've been really, really good lately, buy a carbon pile battery tester. I consider it indispensable for the DIYer both for diagnostics and to avoid needless battery replacement.

@lockheed And to be clear, a bad battery can explain all of the weird electrical symptoms that you've described.

Awesome. I’ll probably buy one because I do work in a shop so it will come useful but this is my daily driver. Thanks for the help I’ll report back once I get the tester

I rechecked my numbers. The voltage drop at the actual battery terminals is only 0.2 volts… at the window switch if I test voltage for the power and ground wires going into the switch it drops from 12.6v to 10v… if I use the nearest multipoint chassis ground instead of the ground going into the window switch voltage only drops to 11.1v
i think this may be a ground fault. Sorry for the misleading info I was very tired this morning and not thinking clearly lol

@lockheed OK, so you probably don't have a bad battery but may want to confirm with a valid load test anyway. Suggest you disconnect both battery post clamps and wire brush posts and clamps inside and out, add a light coat of silicone dielectric grease and re-clamp tightly. Do the same disconnect / abrade / grease / reconnect for all disconnectable connections related to the battery cables, alternator and grounds to body and chassis. Remember, the one you skip because it's hard to access will be the bad one under Murphy's law. Dielectric grease will not impede conductivity.

Ok will do… as far as the actual problem with this voltage drop assuming the battery is not the issue what do you suggest I do? I isolated the single connector that connects to the fuse block that actually supplies power to the cabin fuse panel. It has 3 wires… one is not used, one goes to the ignition switch and I am tracing the 3rd… but voltage drop on the actual battery is only .2 volts while at the switch it’s 2volts

I found what I suspect to be a short circuit… with the switch disconnected if I test resistance between power and ground wires that usually connect to the switch I see a resistance reading of 16 ohms… this should be a reading of infinite resistance right?

@lockheed >what do you suggest I do? Clean up connections as stated. >this should be a reading of infinite resistance right? No, 16 ohms sounds about right for resistance of the window motor. You should forget about the window and its motor and switch and concentrate on the power and ground connections as previously stated.

Ok connections for power primary power cable(s) and ground cable(s) all cleaned and used dielectric grease. Problem still persists. I will disconnect window motor from switch and retest power and ground resistance. That resistance was with ignition switch in the “off position” testing between power and ground into the window switch

@lockheed Again, forget the window motor. If it's only getting 10V when you intentionally stall it, so what? What was concerning about your original post was the 10V at the battery, but you said that's a mistake. You get only a 0.2V drop at the battery when you abuse the window motor. It's fine. The slight drop in RPM from turning on the headlights is completely normal. Headlights dimming then brightening when you accelerate? Unclear to me. Check voltage at the battery when that happens. In short, stalling the window motor should be a momentary event not a test parameter.

Right but why wouldn’t it be infinite resistance at the power+ ground to the switch with it disconnected from battery? None of my other cars do this, old or new… obviously a lot of new German stuff runs off of door control or body control module so it’s not gonna allow you to stall the window but even my 2000’s cars don’t do this. It didn’t used to do this, hence my issue

@lockheed The last time you asked this, I said 16 ohms sounds like you are measuring resistance of the motor. From here I can't see what you are connecting to, I can only guess. It appears that there is no problem except your unsatisfied curiosity. Perhaps if you start a new question and include photos and a wiring diagram if available, someone can answer why your car measures differently from others. Note that most cars now have an end-of-travel detection circuit that senses the sudden increase of current when the motor stalls. It cuts off the power so you don't get dimming lights.

Yes I am aware… in fact that’s often built into the window motor for newer cars, at least German cars. Thanks for your help. My only concern is this was never a problem in the past and it seems like a more recent event. I will continue testing and report my findings once I have them
